# Javascript after ajax call is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML is

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Review" onclick="submit_review_step3_final();submit_review_step3_next();"/>
```

I have these div with the following classes.

```
searchTutorStep3
searchTutorStep3
```

Now in submit_review_step3_final() function, I am making an ajax call to submit data and after that calling submit_review_step3_next() to change the div to be displayed.

But, after running the code, my screen does run the submit_review_step3_next() code and I am unable to switch to the next step.

My code is :-

```
function submit_review_step3_final(){
   var review_description = $("#review_description").val();
   var review_rating = $("#review_rating").val();
   var review_submittername = $("#review_submittername").val();
   var review_submitterphone = $("#review_submitterphone").val();

    var dataString = 'review_description='+ review_description + '&review_rating='+ review_rating + '&review_submittername='+ review_submittername + '&review_submitterphone='+ review_submitterphone;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "database_ajax/write_review.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
          //alert(result);
        }
      });

    reurn false;
}
function submit_review_step3_next(){
    $('.searchTutorStep3').hide();
    $('.searchTutorStep4').show();
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `reurn false;` that will stop JS execution dead in its tracks. You also shouldn't use inline code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ve38qhng/

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting (async to false). It means that calling statement has to complete before the next statement can be called.

```js
function submit_review_step3_final(){
  
  var review_description = $("#review_description").val();
  var review_rating = $("#review_rating").val();
  var review_submittername = $("#review_submittername").val();
  var review_submitterphone = $("#review_submitterphone").val();
  
  var dataString = 'review_description='+ review_description + 
                   '&review_rating='+ review_rating +
                   '&review_submittername='+ review_submittername +
                   '&review_submitterphone='+ review_submitterphone;
  
  $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "database_ajax/write_review.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      // alert(result);
    }
  });
  $.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
  
  return;
}

function submit_review_step3_next(){
  $('.searchTutorStep3').hide();
  $('.searchTutorStep4').show();
  return;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit Review" onclick="submit_review_step3_final();submit_review_step3_next();"/>
```